# Building Metro Apps for beta testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have created a Metro application, but I did not yet send it to Windows Store as it's still in beta. One of my friends was interested in testing my application. To install my application on hes computer I used sideloading, following the steps in this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx . The problem is that, when a press "Y" (yes) and PowerShell   should install my app, it gives an error "*The package or bundle is not signed or it's digital signature is corrupted.* ". What should I do ? I sent him all the files that were generated by the Visual Studio.
I have to mention that :

- I'm using Windows 8.1
- I've developed the app in Visual Studio 2013 Professional
- The target platform of my app is Windows 8.1 (and I have no idea how to change this)
- My friend does not have Visual Studio installed
- My friend uses Windows Server 2012 Datacenter (Could
  this be the problem ? What should I do in this case ? I'm very
  interested that my app to work also on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012
  because this are the OS-es that are used at my office and by a
  majority of the people with whom I work and that could test my app
  before releasing it to the market. )

EDIT : I tried to follow the steps in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835836(v=vs.85).aspx , but my error does not appear to be listed there.
In AppxPackagingOM > Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational I have the next error:

```
    error 0xC00CE014: App manifest validation error: 
    The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 27, Column 8, Reason: Element  
  '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest}VisualElements' is unexpected according
   to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest}Application'.
    Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest}VisualElements.
```

Also in AppXDeployment-Server > Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational I have no errors.

Comment: Have you verified that the certificate is installed under Computer -> Trusted People ?  Use `mmc.exe` to get into the certificate store. If the certificate is missing, try installing it manually by executing it (remember to manuall point it to Computer->Trusted People).

Comment: I installed it both as Trusted People and Trusted Roth Certification Authorities and it's not working.

Comment: @FrodeF., please look again at my post, I edited with an error I found after following another article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question again, I see the obvious solution.

> The target platform of my app is **Windows 8.1** (and I have no idea how
> to change this)
>
> ...
>
> My friend uses Windows Server **2012** Datacenter

You need to target Windows 8 to make it run on 8/2012. And if you check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx), you'll see:

> If you want to create a **Windows 8** version of your app, **you must use
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012**.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I have no other option. Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have created beta app package in release mode not in debug mode. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-99-08-metablogapi/4401.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_2B547D6D.png) is wrong from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx).

Also check out [Can Windows Server 2012 run all Metro (/ Windows Store) applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/480988/can-windows-server-2012-run-all-metro-windows-store-applications)

Comment: Yes, it's release mode. And I've already read that thread. My application is not an antivirus nor does it need to run as Administrator. It's just a media player.

Comment: please look again at my post, I edited with an error I found after following another article.